# Spring's @Validated ignored custom constraint without group

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have controller with method:

```
void save(@Validated(BookingForm.ValidationSave.class) @RequestBody BookingForm form, Errors result) {...}
```

and BookingForm with a field and my custom validator:

```
public class BookingForm {

   public interface ValidationSave {}
   public interface ValidationEstimate {}    
   ....
   @Future
   private LocalDateTime when;
   ....
}
```

Future.java

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FutureValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Future {

   String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.Future.message}";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

I've expected that validator will valid my 'when' field but it does not.
When I removed the group from @Validated it works. Any ideas?
Works fine with @NotNull and others javax validators.

**Updated:**
FutureValidator.java

```
public class FutureValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Future, Temporal> {

   @Override
   public void initialize(Future constraintAnnotation) {
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(Temporal value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       if (value == null) {
           return true;
       }
       LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from(value);
       return ld.isAfter(LocalDate.now());
   }
}
```